# Checking for the content type in html.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming

I need the html.html.twig template to output different classes for the `<body>` tag, depending on the type of content. I know how to do this in the node template, but it doesn't work in the html.html.twig template. We need something like the following.

```
{% if node.bundle == 'page'  %}
  <body class="pageClass">
{% else %}
  <body class="newsClass">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to write code to get the content type of the viewed node, inside the [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8.9.x) file: That value is already passed to the template file.

> - logged_in: A flag indicating if user is logged in.
> - root_path: The root path of the current page (e.g., node, admin, user).
> - node_type: The content type for the current node, if the page is a node.

The Seven theme is using that value, in its [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21seven%21templates%21classy%21layout%21html.html.twig/8.9.x) template.

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,
    db_offline ? 'db-offline',
  ]
%}
```

Since the template file is used for any page, the template file is first checking `node_type` is initialized, and then it uses its value.

Similar code is used in the Bartik's [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21bartik%21templates%21classy%21layout%21html.html.twig/8.9.x) template.

If you are using a theme developed from other users, I would first check the theme is already adding a class basing on the content type; if the theme is already doing that, and adding the CSS class to `<body>`, there isn't anything extra to do, except using the CSS classes added from the theme as selectors for CSS styles.
If you are developing a custom theme, I would add the same code I shown. Once that `body_classes` is initialized inside the template file, adding the CSS classes to the `<body>` tag is as simple as using the following code (a single line).

```
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

The code you wrote needs to be changed as follows, to work.

```
{% if node_type is not empty and node_type == 'page'  %}
    <body class="pageClass">
{% elseif node_type is not empty %}
    <body class="newsClass">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply can do that without any templating by implementing [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x).

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {

    // Add node type body class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-type-' . str_replace('_', '-', $node->bundle());

    // Add conditional body class.
    switch ($node->bundle()) {
      case 'page':
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';
        break;
      case 'news':
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'bar';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 9:

On Drupal 9 node_type is not available, please use:

```
{% set  node_type = node.bundle|clean_class %}
```

Comment: Sweet! This worked perfectly on page.html.twig as well on 9.4.1